# Método en Java para borrar todo de mi tabla en MySQL si el usuario cierra el programa

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy haciendo un programa pero, si cierro el programa y vuelvo a abrirlo, los datos anteriores siguen ahí, y al tratar de ingresar la información de nuevo, como el ID, Nombre, etc... MySQL avisa que los datos son repetidos.

Entonces, como podría saber si el usuario cierra el programa para decirle a la base de datos que borre absolutamente todo?, ojo, manteniendo el nombre de mi base de datos y de la tabla, me refiero a borrar los datos de las columnas, es todo.

Estaba probando con esto pero, me marca error en WindowEvent:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

    }
```

alguna idea?.

También me dice que agregue una librería pero, no se cual de todas es la correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Si no importan los datos por que no mejor los borras al iniciar la aplicación?

Comment: ¿Se puede preguntar por qué quieres borrar todos los datos? ¿No hay posibilidad que más de un usuario esté conectado a la misma base de datos? De ser el caso, ¿no estarías borrando los datos de los demás también?

Comment: uuf, no había pensado en eso, me gusto esa idea, mucho mejor. Pero, como podría hacerlo?, tengo mi clase ConexionBD y mi programa en otra clase, dónde enviaría la sentencia SQL para borrar todo?.

Comment: Si deseas que al cerrar el programa se borren todos los datos. Entonces no deberias persistir con ellos **(no usar bd)**. Justamente las bases de datos fueron creadas para este fin...  La librería es la segunda opción.

Comment: @sstan en este caso, es para un ejercicio de la universidad, no es para la vida real. cuando pruebo el programa he ingreso un dato, se le asigna de ID el #1, si cierro el programa y vuelvo a abrirlo para ingresar datos otra vez, recibo el mensaje de data repetida, entonces debo borrar todo antes.

Comment: @Dev.Joel es un ejercicio para un proyecto de la universidad. cuando pruebo el programa he ingreso un dato, se le asigna de ID el #1, si cierro el programa y vuelvo a abrirlo para ingresar datos otra vez, recibo el mensaje de data repetida, entonces debo borrar todo antes de cerrarlo o al comienzo de abrir el programa pero, no se como hacerlo y donde.

Comment: ¿Es necesario que uses MySQL, o puede ser cualquier base de datos?

Comment: Debe de ser MySQL, ya lo tengo instalado y funcionando, solo me falta resolver este problema debo borrar los datos de las columnas al cerrar el programa, o al abrirlo para poder ingresar datos nuevos sin problemas. Podrías ayudarme?, nunca lo he hecho, no se cómo. @sstan

Comment: La librería debe ser java.awt.event espero ayudarte con eso Y sobre lo de borrar al inicio en tu main cuando llames tu conexión simplemente ejecuta un query tipo DELETE FROM tabla o TRUNCATE TABLE tabla

Comment: pero, cada vez que llame la conexion para insertar o leer datos, va a borrar todo, no?, soy nuevo en MySQL, estoy aprendiendo hace 2 semanas, puedes ser un poco mas detallado?.

Comment: agregue una solución que he hecho con sus consejos, pero no me funciona del todo, espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que esta utilizando una columna `id AUTO_INCREMENT` y bueno ahí toca "resetear" la tabla; si el requerimiento es que se limpie al cerrar el programa, pues va en el camino correcto.

El método `windowClosed` se utiliza precisamente para hacer algún tipo de limpieza justo antes de cerrar una aplicación:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){

    // limpieza ... 

Statement stmt =    conexion.createStatement();

stmt.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE TABLE nombre_tabla");
}
```

Asumiendo que ya tiene funcionando la conexión a la base de datos con la app, solo basta con hacer una query que limpie la tabla pondré un código completo para que vea cómo sería el proceso:

(Sería bueno aplicar un diseño en capas pero eso ya es otro tema..)

```
import java.sql.*;

// public class ... 

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

   String nombreServidor = "localhost";
   String db = "nombre_db";
   String url = "jdbc:mysql//" + nombreServidor + "/" + db;

  Connection conexion = DriverMAnager.getConnection(url,"usuario","contraseña");

  Statement stmt = conexion.createStatement();

  stmt.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE TABLE nombre_tabla");  
}
```

**EDIT**

La creación de ventana es `extends JFrame` y para que se pueda implementar limpieza antes de cerrar la app, hay que implementar una interfaz llamada `WindowListener`, ésta interfaz tiene unos métodos que debemos sobreescribir y pues según los requerimientos, se utiliza alguno(s) de los métodos que se sobreescriben:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public App() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setBounds(10, 10, 300, 300);

        addWindowListener(this);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Limpieza antes de cerrar...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // invocamos el EDT (Event Dispach Thread)
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                new App();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Para el ID, no se hacer el ID INCREMENT, tengo una variable contadora en el programa, y ese número "int" lo guardo en la base de datos, a medida que se van creando mis llamadas, en mi caso. Tengo una pregunta para tí. Dónde debo agregar eso, al final del programa?, dentro de frame en el main?, estoy algo perdido.

Comment: Agrega el código fuente de la clase donde tengas el JFrame y ya miramos cómo debería ser

Comment: hasta ahora lo he hecho como dije anteriormente, te paso un screenshot del código para que me confirmes que es correcto, actualmente funciona. Link: http://oi66.tinypic.com/6ojrsk.jpg

Comment: Mira la respuesta, la voy a editar para que veas un ejemplo de cómo implementar una limpieza justo antes de cerrar un JFrame

Comment: Usar `truncate` solo funciona si tu tabla no tiene relaciones, es decir, que en tu esquema no existe alguna tabla que referencie a esta tabla mediante una llave foránea. De ser ese el caso, solo se podrá ejecutar un `delete` y luego reiniciar el valor de `auto increment` con `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`.